# Show thumbnails 1-12 of category x on any given page

Tags: categories, post-thumbnails

Using wordpress twenty nineteen, I checked the forum but cant find this same question.

I would like to display the 12 most recent posts from category x, using just a thumbnail of the featured image from those posts.

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for help building a block? Or adding this feature to a theme?

Comment: Hi, I wanted to add this code to a page template

Comment: Did you already create a child theme? On what template you wanna display these posts? Do you know about `WP_Query` or The Loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) codex, they have a range of parameters you can use, and example functions.

First setup your arguments,  I have included 2 ways of doing this,  the first being the easiest using the built in [category](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) parameters.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'category_name'  => 'x', // Use the category slug.
);
```

I prefer using the [tax_query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) parameter, as it has given me less problems when using 3rd party plugins.

```
//Setup your arguments
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'tax_query'      => array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => 'x',
    ),
);
```

Lastly run the query and loop through it using a `while` loop.

```
//Run the query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
 if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        ?>
            <div>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
            </div>  
        <?php
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: Hi Warwick, thabks. Will that display thumbs of the featured image for each page?

Comment: @RichardH you can use `the_post_thumbnail` to output the Featured Image.  I have updated my answer with that call.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/

Comment: thanks, you're too kind. It works a treat.